# Html5 app with web service calling works on emulator but not on device

Tags: javascript, android, html, jsonp

I have developed an app in HTML5 using javascript. I have called php web service using json.
Now am trying to execute it for android.

The application works well with web services on emulator, but fails to load the text and  images from server on device.

I tried many solutions which I found on stackoverflow and other links like using hostname, checking wifi of device, INTERNET permissions in manifest file, using WebView but it doesnt work.

Please help.

//This is what I have done in eclipse.

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("hello","start");

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/HTML/index.html");
        Log.d("After load", "url");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Fetching images and text is all done in javascript. It has no problem at all working in browser as well as on emulator. But it fails on device.

//This is my json call function.

```
<script>
    function jsondata(data)
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
         var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
         var main_category = parsedata["mainCategory"];

            for (var i = 0; i < main_category.length; i++) 
            {
                var menu = main_category[i];
                menu_id=menu['mcatid'];         

                var id = document.createElement("table");   

                if((i%2)==0)
                {

                   id.innerHTML+='<br><br><br><td><a href="#" onclick="selected_index('+menu_id+')"><img src='+menu['mcatimage']+'><br><hr color=#000;>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><font face="DEVROYE">'+menu['mcattitle']+'<hr color=#000;></a></td></strong>';
                  document.getElementById("id_left").appendChild(id);
                }
                else
                {

                   id.innerHTML+='<br><br><br><tr><td><a href="#" onclick="selected_index('+menu_id+')"><img src='+menu['mcatimage']+'><br><hr color=#000;>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><font face="DEVROYE">'+menu['mcattitle']+'<hr color=#000;></a></td></strong>';
                   document.getElementById("id_right").appendChild(id);
                }   
            }
            }, 2000); 
     }

    /*-------------calling web service-----------*/
    jsonp("http://hostname/maincategory.php?callback=jsondata");
</script>
```

Here is how I fetched images and text from the web service and displayed on HTML page.
What is the problem with this ?

Today I tried many things like changing `<access origin="*"/>` to `<access origin=".*"/>` and `<access origin="http:hostname"/>`
But nothing worked.

Comment: It is really hard to tell since you haven't posted anything telling us how you load the images or text. Post some example code.

Comment: U loading it as file:// at android browser (native) and calling ajax on diff domain this will be cross domain. (Native webview browser are more strict about security then direct browser).

Comment: @Neha my html files are stored in the assets folder inside www directory, and hence am loading the url file:/// and my domain is called in javascript code where I do the actual processing of data.  In the logcat in android it shows that url is loaded, but I dont get data. I checked and repeated all steps to convert HTML app to android but nothing is working. My project is stuck at this point. Please suggest me something.

Comment: It will sound weird, but on adding time delay it worked on emulator but now the same file doesn't work on emulator also.

Comment: overwrite the webclient of android webview and at onerror and onload resources see whats the issue..or url is loading or not..

Comment: It worked after adding IP address and removing hostname. But the problem now is when I click on 1st tab in navigation bar, it displays only the hard-coded material and not server data, and then after when I go on some other tab and then select the "back" button of the device, I get server data of the 1st tab along with hard coded material. So, please suggest me do I need to work on "back" button of device?

Comment: To be honest I think using IP address is not correct approach(but your requirement are also not clear to me). about back button Yes you need handle it but depends what you want to do in it ..you have to overwrite it something like this..- onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { switch(keycode) case:KEYCODE_BACK //do something.. }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application works on device also now.

There was no problem from android side. I used ajax instead of json in javascript. And it started working efficiently on  device also.